# Self signed SSL certificate is not verified on local when i tried to access from computers own ip

Tags: ssl, certificate, localhost

My goal is to test my web applications ssl pages from another computer on the same network.

I receive an unverified certificate error. I've created a lot of different certificates to fix the error but it did not. Is there any suggestion?

**Error in chrome:**

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

**Error in Mozilla:**

```
SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

[Not secured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsCND.png)

[Secured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeIWS.png)

Comment: In your certificate the IP address should be in a SAN (subject alternate name) entry of IP address type.  Is that how you configured it?

Comment: I configured ip in SAN as a DNS type not an ip. I missed it. I will try this thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Itchydon , i did what you said and the problem was solved. Thanks again.

Comment: A pleasure - I will add it as an answer (instead of a comment) if you could just click the tick next to the answer to accept it - so this question does not remain open would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure in your certificate the IP address should be in a SAN (subject alternate name) entry of IP address type.